# Why does Stack Overflow allow editing posts by people who are not Stack Overflow users?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, anonymous-visitors

Stack Overflow allows non-registered users to edit our posts by using the "improve this question/answer" link. Also the edit is shown by the user name of `Community♦`.

What would happen if a non-Stack Overflow user edited or changed our answer without our permission? I think it is dangerous to allow non Stack Overflow users to edit our posts. Isn't it?

Comment: I assume such edits have to go through the review queue as normal. So they will only apply once 3 reviewers approve them - which shouldn't happen for bad edits.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I think it is dangerous to allow non stack overflow users to edit our posts. Isn't it?

NO. It isn't. Although, I'll agree that many spammers might take advantage of this and try to introduce spam into post but then the edit will not take immediate effect. If an anonymous user (or a user with <2k rep) suggests an edit, It is put in the Suggested edit review queue and requires at least 3 reviewers or a moderator to approve it. If a spam edit from an anonymous user gets approved then it is the fault of the reviewers and they should be punished.

[A request to prevent anonymous users from suggesting edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83457/prevent-suggested-edits-coming-from-anonymous-users) has already been made and declined. The answer on the request also sums up the advantages of allowing anonymous users to suggest edits

Answer (score 4):

Any users less than 2000 reputation or unregistered users can not direct edit posts. They can *suggest* edits which are peer reviewed under [Suggested edits review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits) by community members (i.e. reviewers). So whatever they suggest are accepted or rejected by community. So it is not dangerous.

Comment: The question is asking about people without accounts.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn - Apply the same for both. Added unregistered user's info.