# Require a minimum rep to edit

Tags: discussion, reputation, suggested-edits, sock-puppets

Currently, there is no minimum rep required to edit a post, although low-rep user's edits become "suggested" edits and need to be approved to take effect.

However, such approved edits generate 2 rep for the editor.

I propose some minimum rep be required to edit, probably the same rep required to post a comment.

Motivation:

I have seen this abused as an easy way for a sock puppet account to reach up-voting rep (15).

It occurred to me that as well as this abuse, genuine new users are unlikely to edit well anyway, being unfamiliar with the atypical posting style of stack exchange sites.

Comment: I guess the question is: 'what is the motivation in allowing this?'. There must be a reason they enabled this.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83457/prevent-suggested-edits-coming-from-anonymous-users

Comment: @pat well whatever the motivation of the user making the edit, a good edit is useful/valuable and improves the site: Let the odd sock abuse it - we'll still get 8 edits out of him.

Comment: But if you state it is hard for new users to comply their edit to the SE requirements, why do we allow it?

Comment: @pat my guess is that the queue filters out most of the bad edits (not all!) and it might be a good first step to contribution - suggesting an edit is less scary than making a full post. I just wonder what the stats are for newbies, both quantity and quality.

Comment: Are suggested edits the usual (or even common) route to gain rep for a sock-puppet? I would have thought that posting questions/answers would be a much more lucrative and easier strategy. (And I don't think we're going to suggest users have at least 50 rep before making any posts.)

Comment: @ArthurFischer: it is rather easy to get rep using suggested edits, only fixing a few formatting issues in 7 posts will provide enough rep for a sockpuppet to upvote the owner's main account. Question and answers can be downvoted, unlike suggested edits. Having said that, I don't think disabling edits entirely for these users is the way to go.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: I just don't recall seeing too much of this on math.SE. A couple cases, sure, but there it seems much more common to see a couple mediocre posts created and upvoted to earn new socks rep.

Answer (score 1):

I think this feature-request should only be applied to the top popular sites, like Stack Overflow and Super User, and maybe a few others.

There are already ways in which SO is different from other less traffic sites in terms of general user moderating activities. For example, SO has review audits whereas most other sites do not.

In real life, big cities generally always cost more to live in than in small towns. For example, you could buy a 2500 square foot home in Wyoming for probably the same price as a 650 square foot apartment in NYC.

Also, taxes are generally higher in big cities compared to small towns. So lets slightly bump up the user tax of needing *N* amount of rep before being able to suggest edits.